# Document approval workflow stuck in Start and Wait for an approval when responded from SharePoint UI, but works fine when responded from Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, power-automate, flow, content-approval

Very simple workflow to test how document approval workflow works.

I have a document library in SharePoint and enabled content document library. Created a flow with two steps as shown below

[image]

Now a document got submitted for Approval and as expected the flow is waiting for a response.

From the SharePoint UI, I approved the document. It got approved in SharePoint correctly, but when I check the power automate flow, it is stuck at approval step (i.e. same as when it is submitted for approval)
I got approval request in Teams also.

After waiting for a long time, I finally had to cancel the workflow.

[image]

[image]

**Issue 1: Even after the document is approved in SharePoint UI, Teams not detecting that it is already approved and still showing the form to Approve/Reject**

**Issue 2: Even after the document is approved in SharePoint UI, flow in power automate is not detecting approval status change.**

Now tried the workflow by doing Approve/Reject from Teams.

Correctly waiting for approval response and got the request in Teams.
I approved the request via teams.

Now I see that the flow is successfully executed in the power automate.

[image]

**Issue 3: Why there is a difference in approval workflow for approve/reject doing it from teams/email vs directly in SharePoint?**

Answer (score 0):

Because - SharePoint Content Approvals in document library and Power automate flow approvals are two different functionalities and those are not in sync.

So, when you approve documents from SharePoint UI directly, those will not be tracked by Power automate approvals automatically.

You can either use the SharePoint Content Approvals in document library or Power automate flow approvals or combination of both. But, if you approve the documents from SharePoint UI directly, those will not be tracked by Power automate approvals automatically.

Check below related documentations for reference:

1. [Require approval of documents in SharePoint using Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/guidance/require-doc-approval)
2. [Trigger approvals from a SharePoint document library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/trigger-sharepoint-library)

Comment: This is strange. When I click Submit for Approval from SharePoint UI, power automate listens to it, but does not not listen to Approve/Reject from SharePoint UI. Is this a feature gap from Microsoft?